# Assign .click() to multiple classes using .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to assign event handlers to a bunch of classes that will be dynamically created at various points, and do so in an efficient way.

I thought I could just create a list of key value pairs with the class as the key and the function as the value and then do an .each() loop to assign event handlers to the container element (in this case '.panel'). However, this is causing all the functions to be called on page load. Any idea what the problem is?

```
var functionList = {
                       '.name': nameChange(),
                       '.email': sendEmail(),
                       '.notes': editNotes()                 
    };

$.each(functionList, function(k,v) {    
     $('.panel').on('click',k,v)
});
```

UPDATE: I changed the .click() to .on('click') for clarity (and the problem persists)

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference, since .click() is equivalent to .on('click')

Comment: But I already have event delegation inside my .click(). That's the purpose of the "k" selector

Comment: So .panel exists when the page is loaded?

Comment: yes, .panel exists but not its children

Comment: Ah ok then ignore my earlier comments.

Comment: Here is a simplified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dyt7vcvk/ it appears the key value pairs actually calls the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the declaration of the `functionList` object. You are setting the value of each property to the value of the function since you are actually calling the function for each property. Try removing the parantheses for each value.

```
var functionList = {
   '.name': nameChange,
   '.email': sendEmail,
   '.notes': editNotes                 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used for binding events on dynamically added elements. Give this a try-

```
$.each(functionList, function(k,v) {    
  $('.panel').on('click', k, function(){v})
});
```

Comment: This is equivalent to my code, and has the same problem.